# How to update with join table and duplicate value

Tags: sql, wordpress

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Latitude
ON Latitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lat' AND P.ID=Latitude.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Longtitude
ON Longtitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lng' AND P.ID=Longtitude.post_id
SET P.post_status='trash'


WHERE P.post_type='lv_listing' 
    AND Latitude.meta_value... //duplicate clause
    AND Latitude.meta_value .... //duplicate clause
```

please help me! many thanks

this data from Wordpress database

Comment: Can you provide more information like do you want to keep the duplicate value?

Comment: I wanna set post_status ='trash' at duplicate Lat and Long value!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can update with join condition

```
    UPDATE p SET P.post_status='trash'
    from p_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Latitude ON Latitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lat' AND P.ID=Latitude.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Longtitude ON Longtitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lng' AND P.ID=Longtitude.post_id 
    WHERE P.post_type='lv_listing'
```

for duplicate rows (try this not sure it will work or not :))

```
 UPDATE p SET P.post_status='trash'
    from p_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Latitude ON Latitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lat' AND P.ID=Latitude.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Longtitude ON Longtitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lng' AND P.ID=Longtitude.post_id 
    WHERE P.post_type='lv_listing' and Longtitude.meta_value in (Select  Longtitude.meta_value  from p_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Latitude ON Latitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lat' AND P.ID=Latitude.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Longtitude ON Longtitude.meta_key='lv_listing_lng' AND P.ID=Longtitude.post_id 
    WHERE P.post_type='lv_listing' group by Longtitude.meta_value having count(Longtitude.meta_value)>1)
```

Comment: one more thing I want that it only update with duplicate value. lat and long value in this

Comment: didn't get your question.please elaborate

Comment: I wanna set post_status ='trash' from wp_post when join table post_meta as Longtidue and Latidute duplicate. I don't know how to check duplicate value in that code is "longitude.meta_value" and "Latitude.meta_value".

thanks for your answer

Comment: for all duplicates set status to trash or excluding the first

Comment: for all duplicates set status to trash. Yes, I want it

Comment: *wondering if we could run this update also on Stack Overflows database*

Comment: Checking duplicate for specific column or whole row

Comment: :) @Petter Friberg

Comment: @Ravi specific column

Comment: I tried and got this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from p_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS Latitude ON Latitude.meta_key='l' at line 2